# http.ServeFile () - issue with filename on client

Tags: go

Got an issue with serveFile, I can't get it to get the correct filename on client, this is the code :

```
func serveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,path string, filename string){
  http.ServeFile ( w,r,path+"\\"+filename)
}


    // incoming API requests
    func (gv *GlobalVars) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        switch r.URL.Path {
        case "/GetFile":
        keys := r.URL.Query()
        urlfilename := keys.Get("filename") 
        serveFile (w,r,"c://files", urlfilename)
       }
}
```

If I try to test a download with Curl :

```
curl -O -J localhost:8888/GetFile?filename=index.html
```

I expected it to be index.html in my c:\files\folder - but the filename it gets when curl executes is this :

```
GetFile_filename=index.html
```

I also tried with serveContent and putting the "filename=" in manually but with same result as `http.serveFile()`.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. The file name it saves as is controlled entirely by curl here.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone gets the same issue, as Adrian noticed its nothing to do with Golang - but its curl - when testing on local host you HAVE to specfiy http:// in the url path, it wont work if you just use "localhost:8888/...."

```
curl -O -J -L http://localhost:8888/GetFile?filename=index.html
```